# Can Directx9/10 programs run in Directx 11?

Tags: directx

I am planning to learn to program with Directx9/10 this summer.My computer has Directx11 installed. I was wondering if previous versions will work on it? I tried running a few sample codes from Frank Luna's website I ran into some errors.

Comment: Previous versions should run fine, I have a similar set up, Windows 8 DX11 but still developing and running DX9/10 code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes absolutely.

But if you are using any of the DX helper DLLs (D3DX_xx.dll) that comes with the SDK (and not shipped in Windows), you may need to redistribute those binaries with your application.

For local development, easiest thing to do is just install the DirectX 9 or 10 SDK on your computer. It should copy the extra helper DLLs as appropriate.